# React - How do I handle changes for large sets of dynamic inputs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for the cleanest way to handle input changes for several hundred dynamically created inputs in a form. The problem I'm having is that when I pass down a handler from a parent component that updates the parent's state object as the user types in a given input, rendering the new values in the input becomes slow and choppy.

I've also tried using a separate event handler and "editValue" in state for each child component and sending that to the parent when the user hits a submit button to update its state object, but that seems unnecessary and doesn't meet the requirements for my ticket.

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    // Object will look like this with substantially more categories and input fields per category
    inputFieldsData: {
      personalInfo: {
        allApproved: false,
        inputs: {
          name: {
            approvalState: 'approved',
            value: 'Joe Johnson',
          },
          email: {
            approvalState: 'rejected',
            value: 'jjohnson@gmail.com', 
          },
        }
      },
      companyInfo: {
        allApproved: true,
        inputs: {
          companyName: {
            approvalState: 'approved',
            value: 'ABC Inc.'
          }
        }
      }
    },
  }

  handleTextChange = (category, field, value) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const inputFieldsData = prevState.inputFieldsData;
      inputFieldsData[category].inputs[field].value = value;
      return { inputFieldsData };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          Object.keys(this.state.inputFieldsData).map((category) => {
            <InputsTable 
              category={category}
              handleTextSubmit={this.handleTextSubmit} 
              inputFieldsData={this.props.inputFieldsData} />
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class InputsTable extends Component {
  render() {
    const category = this.props.category;

    return (
      <>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {
              Object.keys(this.props.inputFieldsData[category]).map((input) => {
                <Child 
                  category={category}
                  value={this.props.inputFieldsData[category].inputs[input].value} 
                  handleTextChange={this.props.handleTextChange} />
              })
            }
          </tbody>
        </table> 
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default class Child extends Component {
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.props.handleTextChange(this.props.category, this.props.name, e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          value={this.props.value} 
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

I expect the state object in the parent to update and pass the appropriate value prop to each input without any choppiness while typing.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not caused by using a class vs. stateless component, this makes no sense.  React documentation has never stated that there is a performance gain in using stateless components, only that there **may** be in the future. **Pure components** however may provide a considerable increase in performance because it reduces the number of render operation in the application.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

To the point of the question, I think this is more of an architectural issue.  You are iterating and creating multiple tables each of which contains its own inputs, and holding state in the parent. The parent is re-rendering every single table even if one input is being updated.

1. One possible solution is to implement a shouldComponentUpdate
   lifecycle hook in each InputTable. If the data relevant to this
   table has not changed, it should not update.  Now you have only one
   table re-rendering vs. all of them.

   **See documentation for shouldComponentUpdate**: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate
2. A less elegant solution is to hold each InputTable's state at a
   lower level.  In most cases this is not the correct solution, but
   could solve your problem. I would highly recommend investigating solution #1.

React has [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html) to say about Optimizing performance, and will be an interesting read.  Particularly the section related to avoiding reconciliation will be of use to you.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, 2 of your components don't have any state logic inside them (InputsTable and Child).
You can convert them to what we call stateless components. There a performance gain using them because they carry less logic.
There are a lot of articles talking about them and the benefits of it.

Example of a stateless component :

`const Username = function(props) {
  return <p>The logged in user is: {props.username}</p>;
};`

However it might not be enough. This more complicated but there are other "patterns" to create components with less rendering operations from react.
What is happening there is that your parent component have all the info, gets updates to his state then redraw all his child components.
This might be interesting to read : https://medium.com/@ohansemmanuel/how-to-eliminate-react-performance-issues-a16a250c0f27

Comment: Wouldn't the performance hit from using a class vs. functional component happen when the component is mounted instead of when it rerenders? Can you explain what you mean by functional components "carry less logic"?I deliberately use all class components because it's easier to refactor code when state needs to be moved around. I haven't seen a good argument for significantly improved internal performance by using functional components but I'm open to being convinced.